# Having trouble with IF condition using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I cannot seem to get this `IF` statement to step into the `Call Expiry` part it goes to the else therefore I can only assume there is something wrong with my condition.

I'm trying to fetch the *contract status* from an access table *Investment Data* `WHERE` *Customer Number* is the *Customer Number* on the current spreadsheet. (There is only 1 customer number on spreadsheet).

Is there something wrong with my logic or does the `SELECT` statement return something that is not a string?

Any Help is appreciated, thanks.

```
 If ("SELECT [Contract Status] FROM [Investment Data] WHERE [Customer Number] =(" & "SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh & ")") = "Current" Then
        expiryPrompt = MsgBox("A previous entry from the same contract is currently active, would you like to expire current active contract?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
        Call Expiry
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox ("Entry has been entered into the database.")
        cN.Execute ssql
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Edit 1: In terms of trying to store the `SELECT` I have the following

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim temp As String

strSQL = "SELECT [Contract Status] FROM [Investment Data] WHERE [Customer Number] =(" & _
"SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh & ")"

Set cdb = DAO.OpenDatabase(dbPath)
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
temp = rst
```

I know the the return value of a Recordset is not a `String` I just don't know how I would store it in a variable.

Comment: You're doing a `String` comparison.  The SQL that you concatenate will never equal `"Current"`. Are you trying to compare the *result* of the query to `"Current"`?

Comment: Try not to do everything in one line. Also, it does not look like you're actually executing the SQL query. Execute the query and write the result into a variable, then you can troubleshoot that.

Comment: @Comintern Yes I'm trying to compare the result of the `SELECT` statement with `"Current"`

Comment: @teylyn I'm trying to store the result of the SQL query in a string, but it doesn't seem that simple, I've been trying for a while now but no luck.

Comment: @teylyn I made an edit on trying to store the `SELECT` in a variable but havn't been successful, if you would point out a way to do this that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the value into something so as you can compare it in the if statement. If I understand what you want then give this a try. I am also assuming you will get one result in the SQL statement.

```vb
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn


    strSQL = "SELECT [Contract Status] FROM [Investment Data] WHERE
     [Customer Number] =(" & "SELECT [Customer Number] FROM
      [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh & ")"

    rs.Open strSQL
        If Not rs.EOF Then xx = rs.GetRows Else 'do you code for not getting result 
    rs.Close

    If xx(0, 0) = "Current" Then
        expiryPrompt = MsgBox("A previous entry from the same contract is currently active, would you like to expire current active contract?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
        Call Expiry
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox ("Entry has been entered into the database.")
        cN.Execute ssql
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I also have not amended your code inside the if statement to follow my way I accessing the database.

To answer your question in the coments.
The result will be transposed into the variable. so accessing more than one row or column , you will need to do something like this.

For getting the rows,

```vb
        For i = 0 To 9

          Cells(i + 1, 1) = x(0, i)

        Next i
```

For getting the columns,

```vb
        For i = 0 To 9

          Cells(1, i + 1) = x(i, 0)

        Next i
```

Comment: I have a case where the `SELECT` returns multiple rows, some are expired and current. this case only checks the first row and none of the other rows to see if they are "Current". How would I implement that into the code. Otherwise this works perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: @mYxCHa, if this answers your question, please up vote and mark solved. As for your question, see updated answer edit.

Comment: I tried implementing the loops `For i = 0 To 9 If xx(0, i + 1) = "Current" Then Call Expiry` but I get a subscript out of range error. I know this is because I'm performing and `IF` on something that doesn't exist so I will have to get how many rows there are. I tried a `rs.RecordCount` but this returns a `Long` so I couldn't use it in the `FOR` loop.

Comment: @mYxCHa, use `Ubound` and `Lbound`. So to get the row count, do this, `row = UBound(xx, 2) `

Comment: @mYxCHa, you don't need the `i + 1` the array starts at zero, so just use this in a loop, `xx(0, i)`

Comment: I finally got it all to work, Thanks for all your help!. I did up vote and mark solved. It isn't showing the up vote because I don't have 15 reputation yet. But as soon as I get it the up vote will show up. Thanks!